# I'm getting: TypeError: Member "balanceOf" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, error, truffle-contract

On the line where it says `require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);`  is where I'm receiving the TypeError. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
    
    import "./pSDAToken.sol";
    
    contract pSDATokenSale {
        address admin;
        pSDATokenSale public tokenContract;
        uint256 public tokenPrice;
        uint256 public tokensSold;
    
        event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);
    
        function pSDAToken(pSDATokenSale _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice)
            public
        {
            admin = msg.sender;
            tokenContract = _tokenContract;
            tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
        }
    
        function multiply(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
            require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
        }
    
        function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
            require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
            require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);
            require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are inputting `this` into the function, where it should be: `address(this)`. Solidity is complaining, because it can't find a function that takes in a `pSDATokenSale` as a parameter.

fix:

```js
require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
```

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: I did that and am receiving the same TypeError message. Wondering if it has to do with this:  `contract pSDATokenSale {
        address admin;
        pSDATokenSale public tokenContract;`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that tokenContract was also pSDATokenSale.. I guess you want it to be an ERC20? pSDATokenSale does not have any balanceOf function. Imports are `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";`

Comment: I did something completely stupid and figured it out. Thank you!